# Prestashop 1.4 creating problem with jquery 1.4.4

Tags: jquery, prestashop

I have created a module for the payment gateway integration.It was working fine in 1.3. Now I have upgraded prestashopto 1.4. The jquery is not working fine displaying message 4 is not defined.
This is the head section of my page.

src=”{$url}js/jquery/jquery-1.4.4.min.js”>
This is the code for submission of form without clicking submit button.

[removed] {literal} $(document).ready(function() { $j(’#abc_form’).submit(); }); {/literal} [removed]
It displaying me a message $ is not defined. Really confused with the problem.

Comment: Having trouble with SO's code formatter? http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We would need to see the whole HEAD section of your document to better understand the problem. Also when developing with jQuery is good to use Firebug for Firefox, to aid yourself when trying to debug the code.

Try to open Firebug and reload the page. Then check for the output in the console window (make sure it's enabled), as when you have JavaScript errors, they will be picked up by Firebug.

After you have your errors, you can edit this post to include additional info about your problem, as without it we are not able to help you.

Remember that jQuery 1.4 is being loaded automatically by Prestashop so you don't need to declare it the second time, and this might be the cause of your problem.